# Build AOSP so it has a hidden key value only available to system apps

Tags: android, android-source, android-keystore, android-7.1-nougat, serial-number

I am building a AOSP ROM for my tv box. I have a system app developed and put it in AOSP as a priv-app.

I want to **track hardware itself** so I will be able to uniquely identify the box at server side. BUT I don't want this ID, leak to other apps any user can install on it. (so an adversary can not find out key via installing his app on many devices)

So far I was able to burn a key and reading it via this code:

```
String serial = null; 

try {
    Class<?> c = Class.forName("android.os.SystemProperties");
    Method get = c.getMethod("get", String.class);
    serial = (String) get.invoke(c, "ro.boot.mycustomserialnumber");
} catch (Exception ignored) {
}
```

But this code can be run by any app without any permission. Can I prevent regular apps to access to this value?

Answer (score 1):

Add custom name/value pair in SettingsProvider or You can make own Provider. Guard a name/value pair with custom permission, and give that permission to your app only.